# Service Fabric cluster not displaying nodes after VMSS nodes upgraded

Tags: azure-service-fabric

My goal was to change the SKU of the all of the nodes in my VMSS.

1. I removed all of the nodes in the VMSS associated to my Service Fabric Cluster
2. I changed the sku and updated via Powershell
3. The VMSS correctly shows my nodes running, green across the board

The problem now is that when I view the overview of my Service Fabric Cluster in the Azure portal it is not detecting any nodes.

The existing virtual network correctly sees the nodes.

Any idea's on what the issue could be?

Comment: Which SKU did you migrate to? Was it the Windows Server 2016 image that included Docker support?

Comment: It is the `Standard_D2_v2`

Comment: Ah okay, I misunderstood what you meant. Thought you were referring to the VM image SKU not the Node Type SKU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft support confirmed that what I'm doing is not supported. In order to change the SKU of the nodes in a scale set you need to remove them all, however by removing all of the nodes the association to the SF Cluster gets lost so while you can get the scale set up and running with your new SKU and nodes, SF will not see the nodes.

You need to create a new cluster right now. Apparently they are working on adding that functionality.

Comment: I've been using ARM templates for deploying a Service Fabric cluster with multiple node types. If I need / want to change the SKU used for a particular node type I simply update my template, remove the VMSS, and re-deploy using the updated template. I'm not so sure this'll work if you remove the VMSS associated with the primary node type, though.

Comment: @JZimmerman, you are correct that this only works for non-primary node types.  Also note that if you remove the VMSS for a non-primary node type you will lose any persisted data, so this should only be done if you only have stateless services (or statefull where you don't care about the data).

Comment: @kwill Do you know if Microsoft has plans to support changing the SKU's on a primary VMSS and allowing you to reassociate one to the cluster if it's removed?

Comment: Once Silver durability level is implemented it will give more infrastructure coordination of cluster operations, and this will provide the foundation for functionality such as changing the SKU, but we haven't specifically begun work on enabling SKU changes.  It is a common request so I think it is only a matter of time before this is available.